# Ajax doesn't seem to send my variable string using either POST or GET

Tags: ajax, http-post, http-get

I've been trying to send a sting via ajax so that my php can pick it up and take things from there using the POST method. I'm adapting code from Adam Khoury's Web Intersect 2.0 series. In the process of trying to debug I decided to change the POST method to a GET method in the hope that the variable sting I'm trying to send would show up in the URL, but it remains blank all the time.

Where am I going wrong, this has been doing my head in for about a week now. I've tried setting up different alerts, echo's etc and I just can't figure out where my mistake is. I have one alert in the code at the present time that runs just before the variable string is sent to the page, now the alert displays the code I expect to be sent via POST or GET but isn't.

Below is my current code, just for the function I'm trying to make work, if you'd like more code then let me know, alternativly you can see the form/page at http://www.vwrx-project.co.uk/test2.php, its main goal is to take input from the user, append it all together using the code below, then I can break it apart and get the results I want with PHP after.

```
function cleanURL(){
var params = []; //creates an array to store the form data
var facebook_url = _("facebook_link").value;
var twitter_url = _("twitter_link").value;
var google_url = _("google_link").value;
var instagram_url = _("instagram_link").value;
var youtube_url = _("youtube_link").value;
var personal_url = _("personal_link").value;
var saved = "true";

if(facebook_url == "" && twitter_url == "" && google_url == "" && 
   instagram_url == "" && youtube_url == "" && personal_url == "" ){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Please provide at least one link before clicking submit";
} else {_("submitbtn").style.display = "none";
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("GET", "test2.php");

    if (facebook_url !== "") {
        params.push("fb=" + facebook_url); //creates key value pair and adds to array
    }

    if (twitter_url !== "") {
         params.push("tw=" + twitter_url); //creates key value pair and adds to array
    }

    if (google_url !== "") {
        params.push("go=" + google_url); //creates key value pair and adds to array
    }

    if (instagram_url !== "") {
         params.push("in=" + instagram_url); //creates key value pair and adds to array
    }

    if (youtube_url !== "") {
        params.push("yt=" + youtube_url); //creates key value pair and adds to array
    }

    if (personal_url !== "") {
         params.push("pe=" + personal_url); //creates key value pair and adds to array
    }

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
          _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
}
alert(params.join("&"));
ajax.send(params.join("&")); // sends the array of key value pairs to php and joins enteries with &
```

Answer (score 0):

For GET, you would append the parameters directly to the URL and not pass it to ajax.send.

With the following code, it works for me using POST. Just be sure that you send the request only in case the AJAX object is created - thus in the else branch:

```
    // ...
    } else {_("submitbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "test2.php");

        if (facebook_url !== "") {
            params.push("fb=" + facebook_url); //creates key value pair and adds to array
        }

        // …

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
              _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send(params.join("&"));     
    }
```